# MySql Statement for Year

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create an sql statement to generate 3 rows dynamically without any table .. these will include

```
value1 : 10 | value2: 10
value2 : 11 | value2: 11
value3 : 12 | value2: 12
```

These are the years -1 year from today , this year, next year

Can anyone help me out here

Comment: generate rows without a table? ... How do you mean that?

Comment: they must be generated dynamically like YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)

Comment: why dont't you generate the query from php?

Comment: Just by itself this would be much better handled in PHP. If this is connected to a bigger query, more information would be helpful.

Comment: `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3` Bam, three rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show the table with the years on the front end to the user(s)? then you don't need MySQL - you can simply generate the HTML with the help of pure PHP

If you really need SQL table structures you can use [temporary tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm)

Comment: I know this is not the right way but with the framework I am working on it has to be like this...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1 As value_1, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1 As value_2
    UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) as value_1, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) as value_2
    UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+1 as value_1, YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+1 as value_2) t
```

Comment: I managed to do this .. thanks. The only thing remaining is I want to show only the last 2 digits of the year (e.g 11 instead of 2011) is it possible?